# Keras Embedding index resulted negative value during model training

Tags: keras, nlp, embedding

I am trying to use the `glove.6B.50d.txt` file as the pretrained embedding matrix for my model training as a baseline.  For some reason, I keep getting an error that says: 

`InvalidArgumentError: indices[15,32] = -2147483648 is not in [0, 400001)
     [[{{node embedding_2/embedding_lookup}}]]`

Below is my code:

```
def pretrained_embedding_layer(word_to_vec_map,word_to_index):
    voc_len=len(word_to_index)+1
    embed_dim=word_to_vec_map["the"].shape[0]
    embedding_matrix=np.zeros((voc_len,embed_dim),dtype=np.float32)
    for word,index in word_to_index.items():
        embedding_vector=word_to_vec_map.get(word)
        if embedding_vector is not None:
            embedding_matrix[index,:]=embedding_vector
    embedding_layer=Embedding(input_dim=voc_len,output_dim=embed_dim,weights=[embedding_matrix],trainable=False)
    embedding_layer.build((None,))
    embedding_layer.set_weights([embedding_matrix])
    return embedding_layer

def sentiment_model(input_shape,word_to_vec_map,word_to_index):
    sentence_indices=Input(shape=input_shape,dtype=tf.float32)
    embedding_layer=pretrained_embedding_layer(word_to_vec_map,word_to_index)
    embeddings=embedding_layer(sentence_indices)
    X=LSTM(100,)(embeddings)
    X=Dense(2,activation='softmax')(X)
    model = Model(inputs=sentence_indices,outputs=X)
    return model
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.  The reason for this is my input sample has a lot more words than available pretrained embeddings